# How would I convert data in a .txt file into xml? c#

Tags: c#, database

I have thousands of lines of data in a text file I want to make easily searchable by turning it into something easier to search (I am hoping an XML or another type of large data structure, though I am not sure if it will be the best for what I have in mind).

The data looks like this for each line:

> Book 31, Thomas,George,  32, 34, 154

(each book is not unique, they are indexes so  book will have several different entries of whom is listed in it, and the numbers are the page they are listed)

So I am kinda of lost on how to do this, I would want to read the .txt file, trim out all the spaces and commas, I basically get how to prep the data for it,  but how would I programmatically make that many elements and values in xml or populate some other large data structure?

Comment: Why XML?  It's not inherently easier to search a lot of data if it's XML.

Comment: i am open to suggestions... i just need to make it quite a bit easier to do something like search for specific names.

Comment: Personally, I feel this sort of problem is a classic case for using a database.  I'm a fan of [SQlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) (also available in NuGet).  You would create a database, read and parse the file, and create records for the data.  Then you could ask the database engine to search your data for you.  There are plenty of other approaches.

Comment: Depending on how much the datafile changes, a database may be an overkill.

Comment: okay, this will be mostly static, it is just large... i am guessimating that there will be tens of thousands of entries  like the one above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your csv file does not change too much and the structure is stable, you could simply parse it to a list of objects at startup

```
private class BookInfo {
    string title {get;set;}
    string person {get;set;}
    List<int> pages {get;set;}
}


private List<BookInfo> allbooks = new List<BookInfo>();

public void parse() {
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);  //you could also read the file line by line here to avoid reading the complete file into memory
    foreach (var l in lines) {
       var info = l.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToArray();
       var b = new BookInfo {
          title = info[0],
          person = info[1]+", " + info[2],
          pages = info.Skip(3).Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToList()
       };
       allbooks.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily search the `allbooks` list with for instance LINQ.

EDIT

Now, that you have clarified your input, I adapted the parsing a little bit to better fit your needs.

If you want to search your booklist by either the `title` or the `person` more easily, you can also create a lookup on each of the properties

```
var titleLookup = allbooks.ToLookup(x=> x.title);
var personLookup = allbooks.ToLookup(x => x.person);
```

So `personLookup["Thomas, George"]` will give you a list of all bookinfos that mention "Thomas, George" and `titleLookup["Book 31"]` will give you a list of all bookinfos for "Book 31", ie all persons mentioned in that book.

Comment: This is not a bad solution! i don't know if I will go with this yet, but it does have simplicity going for it. I should have made it more clear, but the books i am referring to are indexes, so each book will have multiple names associated with it (the numbers are page numbers), but this would still work!

Comment: I do have one more question about this approach, I am not sure about the  overhead and wait time of having to read the file with every instance of using it. So how could you save the info that is now all in the lists? would just serializing it on closing work?

Comment: First, I would measure, how much time the parsing takes. If performance is critical, I think you would be better of with a database and proper indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you  want the CSV file to make easily searchable by turning it into something easier to search, you can convert it to DataTable.

if you want data , you can use LINQ to XML to search

The following class generates both DataTable or Xml data format. You can pass delimeter ,includeHeader  or use the default:

```
 class CsvUtility
{
    public DataTable Csv2DataTable(string fileName, bool includeHeader = false, char separator = ',')
    {
        IEnumerable<string> reader = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        var data = new DataTable("Table");
        var headers = reader.First().Split(separator);
        if (includeHeader)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                data.Columns.Add(header.Trim());
            }
            reader = reader.Skip(1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < headers.Length; index++)
            {
                var header = "Field" + index; // headers[index];
                data.Columns.Add(header);
            }
        }

        foreach (var row in reader)
        {
            if (row != null) data.Rows.Add(row.Split(separator));
        }
        return data;
    }
    public string Csv2Xml(string fileName, bool includeHeader = false, char separator = ',')
    {
        var dt = Csv2DataTable(fileName, includeHeader, separator);
        var stream = new StringWriter();
        dt.WriteXml(stream);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
}
```

example to use:

```
 CsvUtility csv = new CsvUtility();
        var dt = csv.Csv2DataTable("f1.txt");

        // Search for  string in any column  
        DataRow[] filteredRows = dt.Select("Field1 LIKE '%" + "Thomas" + "%'"); 

        //search in certain field
        var filtered = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("Field1").Contains("Thomas"));


        //generate xml
        var xml=  csv.Csv2Xml("f1.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
/*
    output of xml for your sample:
   <DocumentElement>
     <Table>
       <Field0>Book 31</Field0>
       <Field1> Thomas</Field1>
       <Field2>George</Field2>
       <Field3> 32</Field3>
       <Field4> 34</Field4>
       <Field5> 154</Field5>
    </Table>
</DocumentElement>

 */
```

Comment: how would this work with more than one entry?  do you need to know the field of the information you are looking for to find it this way?

Comment: If the first line contain header , the column of the DataTable  is named and you can search using these names. with  AND / OR combinations.
Example: 
Suppose header is: title , lastName ,firstName ,category1 ,category2, category3
var  filteredRows = dt.Select("lastName like 'Thomas%' and firstName like'George%'");
var            filteredRows = dt.Select("lastName = 'Thomas' and firstName ='George'");