# C# compare id from text file in filestream

Tags: c#, filestream

I need to fill a text file with information about workers. Then I need to read from the file and search for an ID that user tries to find. For example my file contains ids 1,2,3 and if I try to find id 3 and it matches, then this worker's all information is written in console. Otherwise it writes a text A worker cannot be found.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = "C:\\Temp\\registery.txt";
        FileStream fOutStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(fOutStream);
        int[] id = {     1, 2, 3     };
        string[] name = {     "John", "Carl", "Thomas"     };
        float[] salary = {     3500, 4800, 2100     };
        for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            sWriter.WriteLine(id[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + salary[i]);
        }
        sWriter.Flush();
        sWriter.Close();
        FileStream fInStream = File.OpenRead(file);
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(fInStream);
        int id2;
        Console.WriteLine("Type worker's id");
        id2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        bool a;
        a = sReader.ReadToEnd().Contains(id2);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        sReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So? Where are you stuck? You wrote what you want to do but not what's stopping you from doing it.

Comment: It's a problem if I don't know how to do it. I had a few ideas. One idea didn't work when I tried to search for id 3 and it included numbers in salary section too.

Comment: I added the best working idea to the code. It only prints true or false at the moment as I intended to do for now.

Comment: This is not how SO works. Show us your implementation of the problem and point to where exactly you are stuck or where the error occurs. SO is not meant to be a "program this for me"-service.

Comment: I know SO is not meant to make a code for you automatically. I'm stuck in the end where I need to compare a number that user types with id numbers that are in the file. Now it matches any time when typed number matches with any number in the file. How can I compare only with numbers in id array? Sorry if I ask too much or if I do something wrong again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself to my problem and it worked good enough. It might not be the best solution. I removed bool things and I replaced the whole thing with this:

```
string line;
    while ((line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("id: " + id2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            break;
        }
        else if ((line = sReader.ReadLine()) == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker not found with id " + id2);

        }
     }
```

And I fixed the upper for loop to look like this:

```
sWriter.WriteLine("id: " + id[i] + " name: " + name[i] + " salary: " + salary[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a text file to be searchable, it should be delimited by a separator like  comma /TAB
so modify your code:

```
sWriter.WriteLine(id[i] + "," + name[i] + "," + salary[i]);
```

To search your text file by id/name/..whatever and use AND/OR, you can use the method described here:

[How would I convert data in a .txt file into xml? c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407632/how-would-i-convert-data-in-a-txt-file-into-xml-c-sharp/38409000#38409000)

BTW: Re-factor your code to create the file in a separate method, and the search in other one.