# C# Read All Lines From Specific Time to Specific Time

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get lines in a text file from a specific Start Time to specific End Time e.g. If my Range TimeSpan is FromHours(10) which is 10:00 am, the program should read all lines containing the Start Time "10:00 am" till specific Ending TimeSpan "17:00 pm". Your Help will be highly Appreciated.

Input File is like this:

2016/05/11 10:14:00 blah blah blah dah dah dah

2016/05/11 12:14:00 dah dah dah blah blah blah

2016/05/11 16:14:00 dah dah dah blah blah blah

2016/05/11 17:24:00 dah dah dah blah blah blah

The beginning of each line in file contains the date and time.

This is the code i have thus far:

```
   var FilePath = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\music\\playlist.txt");

     List<string> list = new List<string>();

    var StartTime = DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(10)).ToShortTimeString();

    var EndTime = DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(17)).ToShortTimeString();

       foreach (var line in FilePath )
                {
                    StreamReader read = line.OpenText();

                    while ((inside = read.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        list.Add(inside);
                    };

                    string[] array = list.ToArray();        

       for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
 if (array[i].Contains(StartTime) and is greater than StartTime, Display lines and stop Displaying if you find EndTime )
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                    };

            };
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide the input file sample?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read each line and ignore until you find one with the start time, then just stop when you get to the end time (or past it).  Just keep track of the state with a `bool` to indicate if you are before the start or after.

Comment: You can convert your text file ,to be searchable, to DataTable as described here with examples:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407632/how-would-i-convert-data-in-a-txt-file-into-xml-c-sharp/38409000#38409000

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromHours(10)` is not 10:00 am but it is "duration: 10 hours". `TimeSpan` is not a time point, but a duration.

Comment: @M.Hassan Thanks. I will try to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*: extract the date and filter on it

```
var result = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\music\playlist.txt")
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {' '}, 3))
  .Select(items -> new {
     date = DateTime.ParseExact(items[0] + " " + items[1], 
                                "yyyy/M/d H:m:s", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
     text = items[2]
   })
  .Where(item => item.date >= specificStartTime && 
                 item.date <= specificEndTime)
  .Select(item => string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                                item.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), 
                                item.text));
```